# Unable to set number of neurons of output layer using nntool

Tags: matlab, nntool

Unable to edit the number of neurons of output layer, the field is disabled. When I set number of layers to be 2, even then the 2nd field is locked/disabled. Please help me identify what is the issue. 
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output of the network must be of the same dimension as your target variable, because the error function is MSE and you can calculate MSE only for vectors of the same size. That means the number of neurons in the output layer must be the same as the dimension of the output.

Comment: How to do what? The output is set by you (called `Target Data` in nntool)